# How should I declare for cursor variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

As we know, javascript has no `BLOCK SCOPE`, so when I wrote a for loop like below:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// notice about the `var` keyword
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { 
    // Do something.
}
console.log(i); // shows 4
```

The matter is: should I use `var` to declare the variable `i`?

---

**IF SO:**

When I have two or more consecutive for loop, I want to use the same cursor variable `i`, it will be declare more than once! That simply have problem!

```
for(var i = 0; i < list1.length; ++i) {
    // do something.
}

for(var i = 0; i < list2.length; ++i) {
    // do something.
}

// `i` was declared more than once!
```

In this form, the cursor variable `i` maybe declared more than once, and the code itself implies that the `i` variable is likely to have a scope inside the for block, but indeed NOT.

---

**IF NOT SO:**

Should I explicitly declare all for cursors earlier in the function?

```
var i, j, k; // and maybe a long list that I didn't expected?

// Maybe some other code.

for(i = 0; i < count1; ++i) {
    // do something
}

for(j = 0; j < count2; ++j) {
    // do something
}

for(k = 0; k < count3; ++k) {
    // do something
}
```

If I code this way, I think the code is terrible: it has a long distance between the declaration and use, and obscure about what they are when declared.

If I omit the declarations for them all, and just use, these cursor variables falls into **globals**! That's much more terrible!

---

So I'm asking for a good practice, how to declare the cursor variable in this case?

Need your help.

Comment: There is block scope in _some_ JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: @MattBall well, but it seemed not widely supported, I failed to use it under chrome debugger.

Comment: Both ways are doing the same, and both practices are well established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a variable hoists it to the top of the function and successive declarations are syntactically legal but ignored. So:

```
var i, j, k; // and maybe a long list that I didn't expected?

// Maybe some other code.

for(i = 0; i < count1; ++i) {
// do something
}
...
```

is what the interpreter does under the hood if you declared it multiple times.

Declaring it in this way (variables on the top) is therefore usually what people suggest (and what JSLint suggests).

Answer (score 3):

Typically it's simplest to declare the variable, then use it in multiple non-nested loops.

```
var i;

for(i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    // do something.
}

for(i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
    // do something.
}
```

There is no problem with reusing `i` in multiple loops. As soon as the second loop starts, the value is set to the initial value and everything is fine.

Comment: I don't think the problem caused by `++i` exists, it it not the loop condition. @Alex Wayne

Comment: There is no difference between using `++i` and `i++` in the update part of the loop. The result of the expression is not used in the condition.